# lightweight-charts-python drawing lines from code

Tags: python, charts

is there a way to draw lines, markers and text into a lightweight-charts using python?
I've a GUI with wxPyhton and my chart with data and a file that contains my trades with all data needed. I found no way to draw from my code into the chart, how can I do it?
I first started with mathplot chart+ TKinter but this is a nightmare and looks no good.

Thanks

found nothing helpful in https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python or via google